# Catching Onhover, OnClick events for the items in itemscontrol and get the items in Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, itemscontrol

I'm trying to use ItemsControl in Silverlight. Actually I'm creating a list of items, where user can see a push pin icon on hover upon each of the items separately. And the user clicks on a push pin I've to add the item in another list, that is to say that I've to get the current item in items control, for which the user has clicked the push pin.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BreadcrumbTrail}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Padding="2,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=BreadcrumbPlace}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontStretch="Expanded"  Foreground="#FF9B9B9B" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="14" />
            <TextBlock Padding="3,0,0,0" Text=" >" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFDBDBDB" FontStretch="Expanded" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="14" />
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Now how to show the push pin onhover and how to get the current item.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an invisible button with a pin icon in your data template. Then you can bind visibility property of that button to some property of your item class and change value of that property when `MouseOver` event is fired. It's most likely you'll need custom converter.